# Joomla 2.5.9 : Module installation difficulty

Tags: php, xml, joomla2.5

I'm a newbie on this technology and just started module development after visiting so many links.

But, as whenever I tried to install my developed HelloWorld module via extension manager, I always encounter with the following beneath error:

```
"JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/jainism/tmp/install_511e1c1cc2b04/mod_helloworld/tmpl"
```

It's may be the question be duplicated but I've tried all possible solution which I found here and also at other sites but still my issue's status unresolved.

For convenience, I'm just pasting my xml code below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="2.5" client="site" method="upgrade">
<name>Hello, World Module!</name>
<author>Mohit Jaiswal</author>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see
        LICENSE.txt</license>
<version>2.5.0</version>
<description>A simple Hello, World! modules.</description>
<files>
   <filename module="mod_helloworld">mod_helloworld.php</filename>
    <folder>tmpl</folder>
     <filename>index.html</filename>
     <filename>helper.php</filename>
     <filename>mod_helloworld.xml</filename>
</files>
</extension>
```

And, also I've cross-checked too many times my directory structure as present in above xml as well as file names too.

Please do provide me your assistance.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering if it could be a permissions or path issue. Have you successfully installed other extensions on this site?

Comment: Hi David, that's really become strange and as per your query I've successfully installed other extensions and also able to use my developed components and other things, the problem I encounter with that of module part.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs probably because "tmpl" folder is empty. If you put the default 0 byte "index.html" file inside this folder, the error will likely go away.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't get you by default 0 byte, what I've written in my index.html is as :-  <html><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></body></html>

Comment: It's also fine. 0 byte file just means empty text file, but indeed the default from Joomla now seems to be `<!DOCTYPE html><title></title>`. Anyway, the content really doesn't matter.

Comment: ok, let me check by adding doctype to present index file and will update you accordingly...and thanks for assisting me

Answer (score 0):

If `tmpl` folder is in your module zip then the reason could be that you are adding `<filename>mod_helloworld.xml</filename>` in your xml file.Try without this.

Check this also- http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module

Hope it will work.